# Introduction to Chern-Simons Theory

Tags: reference-request

Does anyone know of any textbooks, or lecture notes that serve as an introduction to Chern-Simons theory? It doesn't have to be devoted to only Chern-Simons theory.

I have basically no background in physics, so I would want something from the viewpoint of a mathematician. I am aware of Freed's papers on Chern-Simons theory, but I would want something a bit more extensive and a little bit less terse.